# Find the points on the ellipsoid $x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 = 1$ where the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $3x - y + 3z = 1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the points on the ellipsoid $x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 = 1$, where the tangent plane is parallel to the plane $3x - y + 3z = 1$.

I'm not sure how to go about solving this. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Which methods have you tried and what are you not sure about?

Comment: @fibonatic I know that the equation of a tangent plane is $f'(x)(x) + f'(y)(y) + f'(z)(z) = 0$. Apart from that, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I know the cross product formula gives me a way to check if two vectors a parallel (it will equal 0). Perhaps, I could use this...

Answer (score 2):

Let the contact point be $(X,Y,Z)$, now the tangent plane is

> $$Xx+2Yy+3Zz=1$$

Comparing coefficients, 
$$X:2Y:3Z=3:-1:3$$

That is $$\frac{X}{3}=\frac{2Y}{-1}=\frac{3Z}{3}=k$$

Now substitute $(X,Y,Z)=\left( 3k,-\dfrac{k}{2},k \right)$ into $x^{2}+2y^{2}+3z^{2}=1$

We have
\begin{align*}
  (3k)^{2}+2\left( -\frac{k}{2} \right)^{2}+3(k)^{2} &= 1 \\
  \frac{25}{2}k^{2} &= 1 \\
  k &= \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{5} \\
  (X,Y,Z) &=
  \left(
    \pm \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{5},
    \mp \frac{1}{5\sqrt{2}},
    \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{5} \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Why did you get $(3k)^2 + 2(\frac{-k}{2})^2 + 3(k^2) = 1$?

Comment: Substitute $(X,Y,Z)=(3k,-\frac{k}{2},k)$ into the ellipsoid $x^2+2y^2+3z^2=1$

Comment: And what's the purpose of that specific step? Is it to find the points on the ellipsoid that contains points corresponding to multiples of the normal vector of the plane?

Comment: To reiterate my post above, I do not understand why we have to perform that step. Please explain your reasoning. Thanks.

Comment: By comparing the coefficients of the given plane and tangent plane, you find the ratios among $X,Y,Z$.  We still need to find the **proportional constant** $k$ for your **point of contact**.  The **point of contact** is the intersection of the ellipsoid and the tangent plane.  By substituting, $(X,Y,Z)$ into the ellipsoid, you can solve $k$ hence the value of $(X,Y,Z)$.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. Why do we need a point of contact? If they're parallel they either never touch or touch at every single point (infinitely many times).

Comment: ***That's on your question:*** Find the **points on the ellipsoid** $x^2+2y^2+3z^2=1$ where the **tangent plane** is parallel to the plane $3x−y+3z=1$.

Comment: Why does the tangent plane equal to Xx+2Yy+3Zz=1?

Comment: @StillFantasy, that's **pole and polar** relation.  For a quadric $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=1$, the polar plane (or line for conic) w.r.t. a pole $(X,Y,Z)$ is $$aXx+bYy+cZz=1$$ See more on **Joachimsthal's notations** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280810/find-tangent-lines-of-a-rotated-ellipse-through-certain-point/3281224#3281224).

Answer (score 0):

Let the equation of the ellipsoid be $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 = 1$. The gradient is $\nabla f(a, b, c) =  \langle2a, 4b, 6c\rangle$

We are looking for the points on the ellipsoid where the tangent plane is parallel to a provided plane, $ 3x - y + 3z = 1 $. In order for any plane to be parallel to another, the planes' normal vectors must be multiples of each other. The normal vector of the provided plane is $ \vec{n_1} = \langle3, -1, 3\rangle$. Gradients are normal to level surfaces, so the gradient $\nabla f(a, b, c) $ will be normal to the tangent planes to the ellipsoid. If $k$ is a scalar value, we thus need to find where $k\vec{n_1}=\nabla f(a, b, c)$

$k\langle3, -1, 3\rangle=\langle2a, 4b, 6c\rangle$

$a=\frac{3k}{2}\\
b=\frac{-k}{4}\\
c=\frac{k}{2}$

All points $\left(\frac{3k}{2}, \frac{-k}{4}, \frac{k}{2}\right)$ that lie on the ellipsoid will satisfy the question's requirements (parallel tangent planes). Plugging this into the ellipsoid equation to solve for valid k values, we get

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}k\right)^2 + 2\left(\frac{-1}{4}k\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac{1}{2}k\right)^2 = 1$$
Simplifying a bit:
$$\frac{9}{4}k^2 + \frac{1}{8}k^2 + \frac{3}{4}k^2 = 1$$
$$\frac{25}{8}k^2 = 1$$
$$k = \pm\frac{2\sqrt2}{5}$$
Now, plug in $k$ to get the points on the ellipsoid where the tangent plane is parallel to the given plane:
$$\langle\pm\frac{3\sqrt2}{5}, \mp\frac{\sqrt2}{10}, \pm\frac{\sqrt2}{5}\rangle$$

Answer (score -1):

Consider the function $f(x,y,z) = x^2+2y^2+3z^2-1$ then the $E$=ellipsoid is given by $f^{-1}(0)$ i.e a level surface. Let $p \in E$ then $\nabla f(p)$ is a normal vector for the tangent plane. For the tangent plane to be parallel to $3x-y+3z=1$, you need $p \in E$ such that $\nabla f(p) = \lambda \langle 3,-1,3\rangle$.

Comment: Isn't it a level surface - not a level curve? Also, could you elaborate on your reasoning? I don't quite understand your proposed solution.

Comment: Eh, that was just a mistake by me. Let $p$ lie on the level curve given by $f(\textbf{x}) = k$. We can find a parametrization $c(t)$ who's image is a small section of this level curve with $c(0) = p$. Then $\frac{d}{dt} (k) = 0 = f(c(t))'|_{t=0} = \nabla f(p) \cdot c'(0)$ i.e the gradient vector at $p$ is perpendicular to the tangent vector at $p$ and so it is normal to the curve. Do you remember this result?

Comment: The reasoning behind making that function $f$ was so that $f(c(t)) = 0$ where $c$ is described in my last comment.