# Find tangent lines of a rotated ellipse through certain point

Tags: geometry

I am trying to obtain the two tangent lines to an ellipse passing through a certain point. I found some similar questions but none that I could find used the ellipse equation $Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F$.

Looking at the below example, I want to obtain the two points E and F where the ellipse and the point D are known.
How am I able to calculate those tangent lines (or points) for a rotated ellipse?

[image]

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774250/finding-the-equations-of-the-lines-and-tangent-to-the-circle

Comment: Please delete the algebraic geometry tag. This is not algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate the plane so that $D$ comes to the origin. The conic equation becomes

$$A(x-x_D)^2+B(x-x_D)(y-y_D)+C(y-y_D)^2+D(x-x_D)+E(y-y_D)+F=0$$

and you can compute the new coefficients.

Now assume that the equation of the tangent is

$$y=mx$$ and you get the condition

$$(cm^2+bm+a)x^2+(em+d)x+f=0.$$

We have tangency when this equation has a double root, i.e.

$$(em+d)^2-4f(cm^2+bm+a)=0.$$

This gives us the solutions

$$m=\frac{\pm\sqrt{(e^2-4cf) (4af-d^2)+(de-2 bf)^2}+2bf-de}{e^2-4cf}.$$

Comment: Ended up using this. Thanks!

Comment: @Stan: glad to know. Not my favorite approach though, as it is not isotropic (and fails for vertical tangents).

Answer (score 0):

1. Purely algebraic approach: from equation of ellipse $f(x,y)=0$ and equation of line $(y-y_0)=\alpha(x-x_0)$, you can get an quadratic equation:
   $$
   \frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=-\frac{f'_x}{f'_y}
   $$
   which is the equation of ellipse (which is the same as given one, but scaled and shifted). From this, you can find its intersection with the given ellipse.
2. A better approach. You find [canonical parameters of ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Standard_equation) and thus the affine transformation to transform it to unit circle. You apply this transformation to point $D\to D'$ and find its tangent points $E'$ and $F'$ onto unit circle with simple geometry. Inverse transformation will give you points $E$ and $F$, since affine transformation doesn't change the tangency property.

Answer (score 0):

> **Joachimsthal's Notations**
>
> - $s_{ij}=Ax_i x_j+B\left( \dfrac{x_i y_j+x_j y_i}{2} \right)+C y_i y_j+D\left( \dfrac{x_i+x_j}{2} \right)+E\left( \dfrac{y_i+y_j}{2} \right)+F$
> - $s_{i}=Ax_i x+B\left( \dfrac{y_i x+x_i y}{2} \right)+C y_i y+D\left( \dfrac{x+x_i}{2} \right)+E\left( \dfrac{y+y_i}{2} \right)+F$
> - $s=Ax^2+Bxy+C y^2+Dx+Ey+F$

Tangent pairs through $P(x_1,y_1)$:

$$s_1^2=s_{11} s$$

See the proofs [**here**](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml) and another answer of mine [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864782/common-point-between-ellipse-and-tangent-passing-through-external-point/2865098#2865098).