# How to find point of intersection with conic section and tangent dropped from a point not on a conic

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Question: We have conic section $-12x^2 + 28xy+4x-9y^2-8y=0$ and a point not on a conic $(2/5,1/5)$, how to find an intersection point with tangent dropped from $(2/5,1/5)$ to a conic section?

My ideas: to use polar points and Homogeneous coordinates

Comment: Please give more detail on what you did so far to try and solve the question

Comment: The tangents dropped onto the conic touch the conic at the points of its intersection with the polar of the point

Comment: We should write the equation of polar point (2/5,1/5) and find the intersection points with conic section, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: The polar of $(2/5,1/5)$ is by joachimsthal $(-12x(2/5)+14((2/5)y+(1/5)x)+2(x+2/5)-9y(1/5)-4(y+(1/5))))=0$ or $y=0.$ So intersecting we get $-12x^2+4x=0$ which gives $(0,0),(1/3,0)$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland how to get the first equation?

Comment: See [this](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pole-and-polar relation with homogeneous coordinates, matrix notation looks more elegant.

- Conic

$$0=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x & y & z \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & h & g \\
  h & b & f \\
  g & f & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Pole

$$(x',y',z')$$

- Polar

$$0=
\begin{pmatrix}
  x' & y' & z' \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & h & g \\
  h & b & f \\
  g & f & c
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  x \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}$$

- In usual practice, we take $$z=z'=1$$
- Polar is a tangent if the pole itself is on the conic; whereas if the pole *"outside"* the conic, the polar is the chord of contact.  Intersection of the polar and the conic are your intersection.

See also another posts of mine [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864782/common-point-between-ellipse-and-tangent-passing-through-external-point/2865098#2865098) and [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395472/equations-of-tangents-to-an-ellipse/4395655#4395655).

Comment: I would be very grateful if you showed in more detail how to find the polar equation

Comment: See details for Joachimsthal's notation [*here*](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml).

Comment: If you are not familiar with matrix operation, please use the following fact: for a conic $$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$ the equation of polar (tangent/chord of contacts) at/from the pole $(x',y')$ is given by
$$ax'x+h(y'x+x'y)+by'y+g(x+x')+f(y+y')+c=0$$

Answer (score 0):

The given equation of the conic is

$ - 12 x^2 + 28 xy - 9 y^2 + 4 x - 8 y = 0 \hspace{15pt}(1) $

And the given point is $(\dfrac{2}{5}, \dfrac{1}{5})$

Using implicit differentiation, with respect to $x$,

$ - 24 x + 28 (y + x y') - 18 y y' + 4 - 8 y' = 0 $

Therefore,

$ y' (28 x - 18 y - 8) = 24 x - 28 y - 4 $

i.e.

$ y' = \dfrac{ 24 x - 28 y - 4 }{28 x - 18 y - 8} = \dfrac{12 x - 14 y - 2}{14 x - 9 y - 4 } $

Now $y'$ is the slope of the tangent line, which is also given by

$ y' = \text{Slope} = \dfrac{ \dfrac{1}{5} - y }{\dfrac{2}{5} - x} $

Therefore, by cross multiplication,

$ ( 12 x - 14 y  - 2 ) (\dfrac{2}{5} - x) = (14 x - 9 y - 4) (\dfrac{1}{5} - y) $

Multiply through by $5$

$ (12 x - 14 y - 2) (2 - 5 x) = (14 x - 9 y - 4) ( 1 - 5 y)$

Expand

$ 24 x - 60 x^2 - 28 y+ 70 x y - 4 + 10 x = 14 x - 9 y - 4 - 70 x y + 45 y^2 + 20 y$

And this reduces to

$ -60 x^2 + 140 x y - 45 y^2 + 20 x -39 y = 0 \hspace{15pt} (2)$

Now we have to solve the system of equations $(1),(2)$, and the solutions are

$(0, 0) $ and $(\dfrac{1}{3} , 0 ) $

Answer (score 0):

*[Discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant)* is a more straight forward way than *polar* and *implicit differentiation*. A conic (Eq.1) is tangent to a line (Eq.2) if and only if the following equations have only one real root pair:
$$\begin{cases}ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0\enspace\enspace\text{Eq.1}\\gx+hy+k=0\enspace\enspace\text{Eq.2}\end{cases}$$
i.e. eliminating *x* or *y* and get a quadratic equation, the *discriminant* should be zero.

In this problem, we have:
$$\begin{cases}−12x^2+28xy+4x−9y^2−8y=0\enspace\enspace\text{Eq.1}\\y-\dfrac{1}{5}=k(x-\dfrac{2}{5})\enspace\enspace\text{Eq.2}\end{cases}$$

By eliminating *x* we can get
$$\frac{-9k^2+28k-12}{k^2}y^2+\frac{16k^2-56k+24}{5k^2}y+\frac{-8k^2+28k-12}{25k^2}=0$$
or by eliminating *y* we can get
$$(-9k^2+28k-12)x^2+\frac{36k^2-114k+48}{5}x+\frac{-36k^2+116k-49}{25}=0$$
Either quadratic equation about *k* we choose, it should have one real root (i.e. double root). Let discriminant be zero ($b^2=4ac$) then we can solve that
$$k_1=\frac{1}{2},k_2=3$$
So the tangent points ($y=-\dfrac{b}{2a}$ or $x=-\dfrac{b}{2a}$) are $(0,0)$ and $(\dfrac{1}{3},0)$.